# How can click on button to get one of components with react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

This is my `html` file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
     <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
     </head>
     <body>
        <button id="aa">another</button>
        <button id="eng">English</button>
        <div class="container"></div>
        <div class="containerAA"></div>
     </body>
     <script src="bundle.js"></script>
     <script src="index.js"></script>
     <script src="indexAr.js"></script>
</html>
```

i want to `click` on `button` (another) it give div with `class` container which is `render` `functions` from `indexAr.js`,
and when `click` on `button` (English), it give div with `class` containerAA
that is `render` data from `index.js` .

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem can be more easily solved when you make use of `React router` and keep a single `index.js` file. You need not to bundle the files separately.

You routes will be in index.js and will look like

```
import {Router, hashHistory, Route} from 'react-router'
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <Route path="another" component={Another}/>
        <Route path="english" component={English}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>, document.getElementById('app')
)
```

You App component will be something like

```
import {Link} from 'react-router';

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
         <div>
             <button><Link to="another">Another</Link><button>
             <button><Link to="english">English</Link></button>    
             <div>{this.props.children}</div>         
         </div>
      )
   }

}
```

I think this is a better an more react style of approach for what you are trying to achieve.

You can follow the following **[youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1iAG6h9ff5s)** for setting up your react-router

Comment: thank u actually this is my index.js i change it to be main one

Comment: Your index.js will only contain the routes

Comment: import WEng from './wEng'
import WAr from './wAr'
class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props){ super(props);
    this.state={im:[]};
      this.componentDidMount();}
   componentDidMount() {
     axios.get('http://localhost:3000')
            .then(function (res) {
              this.setState({
                im:res.data.today.iconday })}.bind(this)).catch(function (response) {
          });} render(){return (
<div><WEng data={this.state} />
<WAr data ={this.state} /> </div>)}}render(<App/>,document.querySelector('.container'));

Comment: and this is my wAr 
 var WeatherAr= function(props) {
render(){
return (
<div className="mainAr">
          <img className="today_imgAr" src={props.im}/>
     </div>          
)}
}
export default WeatherAr;

Comment: routes will be a file ?

Comment: What is the actual problem you are facing

Comment: Your index .js will contain the routes. App will be as I defined and your Another and English will be the components as you have used

Comment: i mean this one <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <Route path="another" component={Another}/>
        <Route path="english" component={English}/>
    </Route>
</Router>

Comment: it ll be i index also?

Comment: and these paths not appear in url up ?

Comment: Once you click on button these links will come up in the url

Comment: i dont have app file this is my folder divsions http://imgur.com/3qDMXot

Comment: You can create one, dont forget to import the components

Comment: i wanna ask this format of code for component 
Is it right ?

Comment: var WAr= function(props) {
return (
<div className="mainAr">
          <img className="today_imgAr" src={props.imagedayA}/>
          <p className="tempdayAar">{props.tempdayA}<span className="degree">&deg;</span></p>
          <img  src={props.imagenightA}/>
          <p >{props.tempnightA}<span className="degree">&deg;</span></p>
          <img src={props.imagenightB}/>
</div> )}
export default WAr;

Comment: I am saying is don't render app from index.js, Whatever you have in index.js, that should ideally be part of App component and in your index.js you can only have the routes. Please have a look at the video and you will understand everthing that I am trying to say

Comment: i have node js in backend i have route /design this is for hole page

Comment: so how path / = component {app}
so instead of / it will like this  
path /design  = component {app}??

Comment: Yes if you have a path design your route will look like `/design`

Comment: please go to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42003230/how-can-set-component-to-button-in-react-js?noredirect=1#comment71183427_42003230