# how can set component to button in react.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router

this is my code screenshot

[index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/df35H.jpg)

**index.js**

```
import React  from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import $ from "min-jquery";
import axios from "axios";
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import WeatherEng from './weatherEng'
import WeatherAr from './weatherAr'
import {Link} from 'react-router';


const urlP=`http://localhost:3000/`;

class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={ 
      imagedayA:[],
      imagenightA:[]
      };
      this.componentDidMount();
  }
   componentDidMount() {
     axios.get(urlP)
            .then(function (response) {
              console.log(response.data,"this is response")
              this.setState({
                imagedayA:response.data.today.iconday,
                imagenightA:response.data.today.iconnight
              })  
          }.bind(this))
            .catch(function (response) {
              console.log(response);
          });
      }
  render(){
    return (
       <div>
              <button><Link to="weatherAr">Arabic</Link><button>
             <button><Link to="weatherEng">English</Link></button>    
             <div>{this.props.children}</div> 

     </div>

    );
  };
}


render(<App/>,document.querySelector('.container'));
```

first component

```
import React from 'react'
export default React.createClass({
  render() {
    return <div>

     <div className="main">
          <img className="bar_en" src="/images/bar_en.png" />  
          <img className="today-en" src="/images/today_en.png"/>
          <img className="tomorrow-en" src="/images/tomorrow_en.png"/>

          <img className="today_img" src={this.props.data.imagedayA}/>
          <p className="tempdayA">{this.props.data.tempdayA}<span className="degree">&deg;</span></p>
          <img className="night_img" src={this.props.data.imagenightA}/>
          <p className="tempnightA">{this.props.data.tempnightA}<span className="degree">&deg;</span></p>

          <img className="line" src="/images/divider.png"/>
          <img className="linedown" src="/images/divider.png"/>

          <img className="tomday_img" src={this.props.data.imagedayB}/>
          <p className="tempdayB">{this.props.data.tempdayB}<span className="degree">&deg;</span></p>
          <img className="tomnight_img" src={this.props.data.imagenightB}/>
          <p className="tempnightB">{this.props.data.tempnightB}<span className="degree">&deg;</span></p>
          <a href="http://arabiaweather.com" target="_blank"><img className="aw" src="/images/aw.png" /></a>
     </div> 
   </div>
  }
})
```

**[second component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2J0ff.jpg)**

and app.js contain this code

```
import Index from './index'
import WeatherEng from './weatherEng'
import WeatherAr from './weatherAr'

import {Router, hashHistory, Route} from 'react-router'
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Index}>
        <Route path="Arabic" component={WeatherAr}/>
        <Route path="english" component={WeatherEng}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>, document.queryString('.container')
)
```

the main idea want to main page be just contain buttons of arabic ,english
and when click on arabic `/english` go to `arabic/english` component with this.state which is contain data that i set to it from url in index

Note just copy link for screenshots

Comment: Please don't include code as screenshots - it makes it harder for your question to be found in search, and isn't friendly towards people who are using screen readers. You should edit the relevant sections of code into your question.

Comment: thank u i add code up So now the problem is clear?

Comment: What's your specific question?

Comment: how i can set compnent page to button 
so when click on this button it get component page

Comment: i see you are using Link component , check if this question helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30115324/pass-props-in-link-react-router

Comment: you mean put like this               <button><weatherAr to="weatherAr">Arabic</weatherAr><button>

             <button><weatherEng to="weatherEng">English</weatherEng></button>    
i try this but its still same error

Comment: second thing how i can send {this.state} in index.js

Comment: @Shubham Khatri

Comment: Why do you need this.componentDidMount(); in the constructor?, componentDidMount should be called automatically.

Comment: Does index.js contain the App component

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the values as props to your child components. 
In your **app** component add:

```
render(){
    return (
       <div>
              <button><Link to="weatherAr">Arabic</Link><button>
             <button><Link to="weatherEng">English</Link></button>    
             {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, { imagedayA: this.state.imagedayA, imagenightA: this.state.imagedayA})}

     </div>

    );
```

This will allow you to read the value of imagedayA as props in your child components. 
Now you can do (**WeatherAr**):

```
import React from 'react'
export default React.createClass({
  render() {
    return <div>

     <div className="main">
          // Here you can access the value:
          {this.props.imagedayA}
          <img className="bar_en" src="/images/bar_en.png" />  
          // more code ...
     </div> 
   </div>
  }
})
```

Comment: why it give me error 
ERROR in ./views/index.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for <button> (53:5)

  51 |              <div>{this.props.children}</div> 
  52 | 
> 53 |      </div>
     |      ^
  54 |         
  55 |     );
  56 |   };

Comment: ERROR in ./views/index.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for <button> (56:5)

  54 |              })}
  55 | 
> 56 |      </div>
     |      ^
  57 |         
  58 |     );

Comment: I copied and pasted your code, is missing a closing tag on <button><Link to="weatherAr">Arabic</Link><button>. should be **<button><Link to="weatherAr">Arabic</Link></button>**

Comment: Uncaught Error: <Link>s rendered outside of a router context cannot navigate.(…) i got this error

Answer (score 0):

You could have an external js file, that handles your images, and import it in both of your components.

```
Weather.js

export default class Weather extends React.Component {
  ...your implementation...
}
```

And then

```
EngWeather.js

import Weather from './Weather'

export default class EngWeather extends Weather {
  ...your implementation...
}
```